# How to internationalize title in Flask?

Tags: html, flask, internationalization, jinja2, flask-babel

I'm trying to internationalize a flask webpage and I did every variable but couldn't succeed at internationalizing the title.

My code is below:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}{% block title %}Test Title{% endblock %}{% block content %}
```

I already tried this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}{% block title %}_(Test Title){% endblock %}{% block content %}
```

and this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}{% block title %}_("Test Title"){% endblock %}{% block content %}
```

both of them didn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: it's not clear what you're going to do with that. do you want "test title" to show up in another language? add an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, I would like to change "Test Title" something like "Test Başlığı". Problem is I couldn't get it as a parameter like: 
#: templates/test.html:8
msgid "Test Title"
msgstr ""
in my messages.po file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third one proposition is the closest, because "Test Title" is a string so it needs quotes, but you must put it into double braces `{{`. When your string is surrounded by `_( )` it becomes a variable and the template needs the double braces to display it.

The result is : `{{ _("Test Title") }}`